# Discrepancy in EFI\BOOT Folder Presence Between ARM and AMD64 ISOs, and UEFI Support Verification for ARM ISOs

Tags: uefi, iso, arm

Why does the ARM ISO not contain the EFI\BOOT folder, while the AMD64 ISO does? And how can one verify if an ARM ISO supports UEFI without checking the EFI\BOOT folder?